# False sunset and false sunrise time estimation

Tags: optics, scattering, atmospheric-science, refraction, geometric-optics

[False sunset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sunset) and [false sunrise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sunrise)  are described .

Here is a sample day rise and set time according to AccuWheather site and calculated value of sunrise and sunset in my country. Could you please help me to figure out the calculation formula or calculation it self if it is possible.

[image]

if it is not possible for location based answer you may use **under normal conditions**.

thanks.

Comment: To calculate would require us to have knowledge of the various layers of the atmosphere and their scattering properties, which is not very common.

Comment: I'm aware of those issues but some hacking may be applied calculating an estimated version.

Comment: There is some source code over at [astronomy.SE for twilight calculations](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/24305/18054).